# login screen background problem

Tags: login, desktop-background

I installed variety on ubuntu 14.04 and customize login screen support option to set variety wallpaper set as login screen background. i copied my wallpaper directory into ~/Pictures directory and set access permission as 777 to both directory and pictures. after that wallpaper showed up correctly on login screen and everything works well.

after few days login screen didn't change according to the desktop wallpaper and it turned into ash color and when i open unity tweak tool's login settings It looks like this. [image]

how do i reset these settings and solve this problem. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remove login screen support option to set variety wallpaper set as login screen background option in variety and then open ubuntu tweak - tweaks - login settings- unlock the lock symbol at top right corner then you should be able to change login background.

Comment: This solution works for me.`gsettings reset com.canonical.unity-greeter background` and `gsettings reset com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds` after that `gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'false'`finally `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active 'true'` This solution works well with variety too.